# Yii2: JsonParse no funciona por default

Tags: php, yii2

El punto es que al acceder a mi controlador `Entrenamiento` por medio del navegador (URL), éste me devuelve formato XML a menos que especifique en la petición `Content-type: application/json`. Según la documentación esto debería funcionar por default (JsonParse) al establecerlo en el archivo de configuración.

Dejo la configuración en mi archivo `frontend/config/main.php`:

```
$params = array_merge(
    require(__DIR__ . '/../../common/config/params.php'),
    require(__DIR__ . '/../../common/config/params-local.php'),
    require(__DIR__ . '/params.php'),
    require(__DIR__ . '/params-local.php')
);

return [
    'id' => 'app-frontend',
    'basePath' => dirname(__DIR__),
    'bootstrap' => ['log'],
    'controllerNamespace' => 'frontend\controllers',
    'components' => [
        'user' => [
            'identityClass' => 'common\models\User',
            'enableAutoLogin' => true,
        ],
        'log' => [
            'traceLevel' => YII_DEBUG ? 3 : 0,
            'targets' => [
                [
                    'class' => 'yii\log\FileTarget',
                    'levels' => ['error', 'warning'],
                ],
            ],
        ],
        'urlManager' => [
            'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
            'enableStrictParsing' => true,
            'showScriptName' => false,
            'rules' => [
                ['class' => 'yii\rest\UrlRule', 'controller' => 'entrenamiento'],

                '<controller:\w+>/' => '<controller>/index',
                '<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/view',
                '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
                '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
            ],
        ],
        'request' => [
            'parsers' => [
                'application/json' => 'yii\web\JsonParser',
            ]
        ],
        'errorHandler' => [
            'errorAction' => 'site/error',
        ],
    ],
    'params' => $params,
];
```

En mi controlador (`frontend/controllers/EntrenamientoController.php`) tengo:

```
namespace frontend\controllers;

use yii\rest\ActiveController;

/**
* Entrenamiento controller
*/
class EntrenamientoController extends ActiveController
{
    public $modelClass = 'common\models\Entrenamiento';
}
```

Comment: Se me ocurren dos posibles errores, o estás llamando a otro main.php en tu index.php o estas trabajando en localhost. Chequealo y me decis :).

Comment: Tanto en servidor como en localhost me da el mismo resultado. Utilizo una ruta como la siguiente: `miproyecto/frontend/web/index.php?r=entrenamiento`.

Answer (score 1):

Algunos ejemplos para retornar en formato json desde un controlador pueden ser de estas maneras:

Directamente desde una acción

```
use Yii;
use yii\web\Response;

...

public function actionIndex()
{
    Yii::$app->response->format = Response::FORMAT_JSON;
}
```

Si hay mas acciones que necesitan retornar en formato json configurar su controlador de esta manera

```
/**
 * @inheritdoc
 */
public function behaviors()
{
    return [
        [
            'class' => ContentNegotiator::className(),
            'only' => ['index', 'view']
            'formats' => [
                'application/json' => Response::FORMAT_JSON,
            ],
        ],
    ];
}
```

Si es una RESTful API lo puede hacer desde la configuración general de Yii

```
'contentNegotiator' => [
    'class' => ContentNegotiator::className(),
    'formats' => [
        'application/json' => Response::FORMAT_JSON,
        'application/xml' => Response::FORMAT_XML,
    ],
],
```